# Pytest: how to do snapshot tests for Pandas DataFrame while failed

Tags: python, pandas, pytest, snapshot

I have two data frames:

- `df1`: it originated from a csv file, and has been cleaned by drop unwanted data.
- `df2`: it was a validated data frame from the previous success results. We save it into a file and load it back when testing.

Now we write a test:

```py
import pandas as pd

def test_data_cleaning_process():
    df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.csv')
    # execute target function
    df1 = cleanup(df1)

    # compare dfs
    assert df1.equals(df2)
```

It is OK while we pass the tests. When the test failed, the console output is hard to find out the unmatched data.

For example

```py
def test_for_failure():
    import pandas as pd
    data1 = {
        'A': [1,2,3,4],
        'B': [1,2,3,4],
        'C': [1,2,3,4],
        'D': [1,2,3,4],
        'E': [1,2,3,4],
        'F': [1,2,3,4],
        'G': [1,2,3,4],
    }
    data2 = {
        'A': [1,2,3,4],
        'B': [1,2,3,9], # We change 4 to 9 for failure
        'C': [1,2,3,4],
        'D': [1,2,3,4],
        'E': [1,2,3,4],
        'F': [1,2,3,4],
        'G': [1,2,3,4],
    }
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

    assert df1.equals(df2)
```

The console output for pytest:

```
...
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
    
>       assert df1.equals(df2)
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <bound method NDFrame.equals of    A  B  C  D  E  F  G\n0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1\n1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2\n2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3\n3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4>(   A  B  C  D  E  F  G\n0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1\n1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2\n2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3\n3  4  9  4  4  4  4  4)
E        +    where <bound method NDFrame.equals of    A  B  C  D  E  F  G\n0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1\n1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2\n2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3\n3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4> =    A  B  C  D  E  F  G\n0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1\n1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2\n2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3\n3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4.equals
```

The dataframes:

```
# df1
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
# df2
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3
3   4   9   4   4   4   4   4
```

Only one row is unmatched, but pytest prints out useless info for failed cases when the data frame is big.

### Questions

1. How to just print out which row is unmatched (row index 3 in this case) while failed? Or generate a diff file for review.
2. Is there any tool can let me overwrite the current data into the snapshot file even if it failed?
3. What is the best practice to test the cleaning process to ensure refactoring won't change the results?

Answer (score 2):

Use [**pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) to write the pandas dataframe tests, Like this

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
```

It raises a much more clear traceback, with the index, and what's mismatched in both the data frames

```
AssertionError:

DataFrame.iloc[:, 1] (column name="B") values are different (25.0 %)
[index]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
[left]:  [1, 2, 3, 4] 
[right]: [1, 2, 3, 9]
```